# Why do I get "The method createLL() is undefined for the type LinkedListUse" error when calling from same package in Java?

Tags: java, class, oop, linked-list, java-package

Class linkedListUse

```
package linkedlists;

public class LinkedListUse {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
        Node head=createLL();
        printLL(head);
    }

}
```

Class CreateAndPrintLL

```
package linkedlists;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class CreateAndPrintLL {
    
    public Node createLL() {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        int data=sc.nextInt();
        Node head=null;
        while (data!=-1) {
            Node currentNode=new Node(data);
            if(head==null) {
                head=currentNode;
            }
            else {
                Node tail=head;
                while(tail.next!=null) {
                    tail=tail.next;
                }
                tail.next=currentNode;
            }
            data=sc.nextInt();
        }
        return head;
    }
    
    public void printLL(Node head) {
        Node temp=head;
        while(temp!=null) {
            System.out.print(temp.next);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    
}
```

I'm facing error in my code, int main method i'm trying to call createLL method but it's showing me-**The method createLL() is undefined for the type LinkedListUse** error inspite of bioth the classes being in the same package....WHY IS THAT?

Comment: Because you cannot call an instance method without having an instance. `createLL` is defined in class `CreateAndPrintLL`, so you need to have an object instance of that class on which to call this method.

Comment: It's not working even after making the methods static  @knittl

Comment: The method is still part of a different class and needs to be qualified. Otherwise, how should the compiler know which method you want to call? Compilers cannot read minds.

Comment: So how do I resolve it @knittl?

Comment: @092_AshitaVerma, did you check below? Does that resolve it?

Comment: But why do i need to create an instance even the method is static?

Answer (score 0):

Your main method is trying to access methods of another class. You would need to create an instance of `CreateAndPrintLL` and call the methods in that instance:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CreateAndPrintLL ll = new CreateAndPrintLL();
        Node head = ll.createLL();
        ll.printLL(head);
    }
```

There is an unrelated error in your `CreateAndPrintLL` class, in the `printLL` method: the loop doesn't modify `temp`, so once it makes an iteration it will keep making more iterations without end.

Fix it like this:

```
    public void printLL(Node head) {
        Node temp=head;
        while(temp!=null) {
            System.out.print(temp.data); // Depends on how Node exposes data
            temp = temp.next;            // Must move to the next node
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

NB: As I didn't see the `Node` class I made the assumption that a node's data is accessed via a `data` instance variable. Adapt if needed.